# How to get max values for distinct elements in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have records in my collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c37a71c54956d08afb590ef"),
    "user_id" : 45,
    "result" : 9,
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c37a7ad54956d08afb590f0"),
    "user_id" : 1,
    "result" : 3,
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c37a80254956d08afb590f1"),
    "user_id" : 45,
    "result" : 10,
}
```

How to get distinct records with max values (result) for each user (user_id field is unique) ?
I expect result like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c37a80254956d08afb590f1"),
    "user_id" : 45, //distinct user_id
    "result" : 10, //max result for user
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c37a7ad54956d08afb590f0"),
    "user_id" : 1, //distinct user_id
    "result" : 3, //max result for user
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $sort: { result: -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$user_id",
            result: { $first: "$result" },
            o_id: { $first: "$_id" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: "$o_id",
            user_id: "$_id",
            result: 1
        }
    }
])
```

You need to use [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) first to be able to capture both `_id` and `result` from highest `result` document using [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) and `$first` operators. Output:

```
{ "result" : 3, "_id" : ObjectId("5c37a7ad54956d08afb590f0"), "user_id" : 1 }
{ "result" : 10, "_id" : ObjectId("5c37a80254956d08afb590f1"), "user_id" : 45 }
```

Comment: can you help with the same query but between two dates (Type Date) ? I can't make it out ... there is time field in every record, it always gives me an error...

Comment: @socm_ please open another question and paste the error you're getting